# AMPscript Lookup fails to find record

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

Having trouble with lookup not returning what's expected.

The `@LOTeamName` is what I'm having trouble returning.  No errors when I run it, it just doesn't return anything even though I know it's there.

```
%%[

/* Find LO Info */
/* Find OwnerID - Look in contacts first then leads */
Set @rsContacts = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","ID",_Subscriberkey)

If RowCount(@rsContacts) > 0 Then
 Set @OwnerID = Field(Row(@rsContacts,1),"OwnerID")
Else

 Set @rsLeads = LookupRows("Lead_Salesforce","ID",_Subscriberkey)

 If RowCount(@rsLeads) > 0 Then
  Set @OwnerID = Field(Row(@rsLeads,1),"OwnerID")
 EndIf

EndIf

)

/* Find user info */
If Not Empty(@OwnerID) Then

 Set @rsUsers = LookupRows("User_Salesforce","Id",@OwnerID)

 if RowCount(@rsUsers) > 0 then

  Set @LOFirstName = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"FirstName")
  Set @LOLastName = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"LastName")
  Set @LOTitle = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Title")
  Set @LO_NMLS_Number = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"LO_NMLS_Number__c")
  Set @LOStreet = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Street")
  Set @LOCity = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"City")
  Set @LOState = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"State")
  Set @LOPostalCode = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"PostalCode")
  Set @LOPhone = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Phone")
  Set @LOMobilePhone = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"MobilePhone")
  Set @LOFax = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Fax")
  Set @LOEmail = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Email")
  Set @LO_Branch_URL = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"LO_Branch_URL__c")
  Set @LOBranch_NMLS_Number = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Branch_NMLS_Number__c")
  Set @LO_Photo = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"CC_PhotoURL__c")

 EndIf 

 If Not Empty (@LOBranch_NMLS_Number) Then

  Set @LOTeamName = Lookup("BranchWebsite", "BranchTeamName_Override__c", "Branch_NMLS_Number__c", @LOBranch_NMLS_Number)

 endif

EndIf
]%%
```

---

Comment: Have you verified that (a)LOBranch_NMLS_Number is definitely not empty? It appears a definition of (a)LOTeamName is dependent on this var.

Comment: I have the "If Not Empty (@LOBranch_NMLS_Number) " before the lookup.  Does that not suffice? @Gortonington

Comment: I understand that, I am saying if LOBranch_NMLS_Number is empty Then LOTeamName will not fill, regardless if it has value or not.  So have you verified that on your tests that LOBranch_NMLS_Number does have a value?

Comment: Yes on my tests I have made sure that LOBranch_NMLS_Number does have value

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the field actually has a Null value instead of EMPTY. AMPscript doesn't evaluate for NULL when it's comparing against an attribute.

To get around this try:

```
IF @LOBranch_NMLS_Number != "" or @LOBranch_NMLS_Number is NOT NULL THEN
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally debug lookup challenges with a series of outputs.  Using a debug flag variable allows me to turn the debugging output on and off.

My rule of thumb for debugging is:

> Output variable names and values after every lookup and before every conditional

Doing this will help you trace the path through your conditionals.

```
%%[

var @debug
set @debug = 1

/* Find LO Info */
/* Find OwnerID - Look in contacts first then leads */

Set @rsContacts = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","ID",_Subscriberkey)

If RowCount(@rsContacts) > 0 Then
 Set @OwnerID = Field(Row(@rsContacts,1),"OwnerID")
Else

 Set @rsLeads = LookupRows("Lead_Salesforce","ID",_Subscriberkey)

 If RowCount(@rsLeads) > 0 Then
  Set @OwnerID = Field(Row(@rsLeads,1),"OwnerID")
 EndIf

EndIf

/* Find user info */
If Not Empty(@OwnerID) Then

 Set @rsUsers = LookupRows("User_Salesforce","Id",@OwnerID)

 if RowCount(@rsUsers) > 0 then

  Set @LOFirstName = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"FirstName")
  Set @LOLastName = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"LastName")
  Set @LOTitle = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Title")
  Set @LO_NMLS_Number = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"LO_NMLS_Number__c")
  Set @LOStreet = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Street")
  Set @LOCity = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"City")
  Set @LOState = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"State")
  Set @LOPostalCode = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"PostalCode")
  Set @LOPhone = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Phone")
  Set @LOMobilePhone = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"MobilePhone")
  Set @LOFax = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Fax")
  Set @LOEmail = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Email")
  Set @LO_Branch_URL = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"LO_Branch_URL__c")
  Set @LOBranch_NMLS_Number = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"Branch_NMLS_Number__c")
  Set @LO_Photo = Field(Row(@rsUsers,1),"CC_PhotoURL__c")

 EndIf 

 If Not Empty (@LOBranch_NMLS_Number) Then
   Set @LOTeamName = Lookup("BranchWebsite", "BranchTeamName_Override__c", "Branch_NMLS_Number__c", @LOBranch_NMLS_Number)
 endif

EndIf

if @debug == 1 then 
    output(concat("<br>RowCount(@rsContacts): ", RowCount(@rsContacts)))
    output(concat("<br>RowCount(@rsLeads): ", RowCount(@rsLeads)))
    output(concat("<br>ownerId: ", @ownerId))
    output(concat("<br>RowCount(@rsUsers): ", RowCount(@rsUsers)))
    output(concat("<br>@LOBranch_NMLS_Number: ", @LOBranch_NMLS_Number))
    output(concat("<br>@LOTeamName: ", @LOTeamName))
endif

]%%
```

**Reference**

- [Output](https://ampscript.guide/output)
- [Concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat)